# Phaser game perspective

Tags: html5-canvas, game-physics, phaser-framework

I'm new with Phaser and I would to receive some advice on how to start building this type of game. Any example, ideas, tutorials are welcome.
Thanks in advance!.

http://appcrawlr.com/ios/beat-mp3

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Phaser is focused on 2D graphics, so sprites bitmaps tilemaps etc. The sprites can rotate and zoom, so with zooming and you can simulate the 3D perspective like in the example image. In other words, as long as you don't need the perspective of the 4 lanes to change (so you won't need a 3D model) you can make such a thing in Phaser.

Phaser is especially well suited for animated user-interface and particle effects. So animating the "perfect" and "combo" texts, and the white transparent stars at the bottom is relatively easy in Phaser, by using the build in [tweens](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Tween.html) and [emitters](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Particles.Arcade.Emitter.html) etc.

Your question about how to start building this type of game is too broad for stack overflow. I think it's better to ask this question in the Phaser forum at [www.html5gamedevs.com](http://www.html5gamedevs.com)

Comment: Thanks for your advice @BdR!

Comment: This tutorial is great for this type of thing... http://codeincomplete.com/posts/javascript-racer-v1-straight/ The math behind the setting the y position, speed and scaling is what you need.